# Hide Text with Image Using Jquery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I apologise in advance if this is very simple, but I do not have much knowledge in Jquery.

I have a website that automates a pass / fail function for members.

On the users profile, where they are passed, I want this to display an image.  I would like the database to still record the word PASSED and for this to be only replaced on the page so that the database doesn't get altered.

**The text looks like this**

```
  <div class="member-field-type"><i class="member-icon-ok"></i>
  <span>Status</span></div> <div class="member-field-value">Passed</div>
```

Because the class  "member-field-type" and "member-field-value" is used several times on the page, I cannot change all instances of this.  This is why I cannot do this as css.

I would like to HIDE the "Passed" text only within the DIV and show an image instead.

I have tried various ways such as this but cannot get it to work.

```
 var str="<div class="member-field-value">Passed</div>";
 document.write(str.replace("Passed", "<img alt="Passed" src="/passed.png"/>"));
 }
```

And in any case I think the above would replace rather than hide.

Can anyone help. After 2 days searching the internet and try various code suggestions, Im at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example wraps the text in a span and hides it

```
$('.member-field-value').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === 'Passed'; 
}).contents().wrap('<span style="display:none"></span>')
       .end().append('<img src="pass.jpg"/>');
```

Comment: This feels like it should work, but the text isn't changing to the image.

Comment: @user2903829 It works for me. Does the image not appear at all?

Comment: No just the text, but maybe its me. I have never worked with scripts before. What goes before and after and do I need to call a jquery file?  Here is my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4MLX3/1/

Comment: @user2903829 http://jsfiddle.net/4MLX3/5/ You were missing the closing `});` and you misspelled the `ID` (well it had capital letter)

Comment: Sorry yes - that works.  Just can get it to work in the actual website for some reason but will figure that out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a great deal easier and more efficient for your code if you can just add an id attribute to the div:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="member-field-value">Passed</div>
```

But if you absolutely have to do it without you will need to loop through each of your divs with the class `member-field-value`, find the one with the correct content and replace it with your image:

```
$('.member-field-value').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);

    // Check if the content matches
    if($this.html() == "Passed"){
        // Replace the content with the new wrapped text and image
        $this.html('<div id="passedText">Passed</div><img alt="Passed" src="/passed.png"/>');

        // Hid the text
        $this.find('#passedText').hide();
    }
});
```

If instead you can just add the `id` this is all you'll need:

```
// Replace the text
$('#myDiv').html('<div id="passedText">Passed</div><img alt="Passed" src="/passed.png"/>');

// Hide the text
$('#myDiv #passedText').hide();
```

Comment: Unforrunately I cannot allocate an ID because its a wordpress CMS. If I could I would have simply done this via CSS.

Couldnt get the above to work Im afraid.

Comment: Ok no problem. The first code example in my answer should work for you then :)